# Basic Fourier Series Question

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, fourier-series, education

Let $f$ be a $2π$ periodic function where $$f(x) = \frac{π - x}2$$ over $[0, π]$.

It is known that the Fourier series of $f$ is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx}n$$

At which points in $[-π, π]$ does $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}n$$ holds?

Comment: The Fourier series will agree with the function almost everywhere. (I believe that) On compact subsets on which the periodic extension of the function is continuous, it will converge everywhere. At points of discontinuity of the periodic extension, the Fourier series will converge to the average value of the discontinuity.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, from the Fourier series given this periodic function is a sawtooth wave, with discontinuities upwards and downward slopes. I suspect the definition for $f(x)$ on the first line should be over $[0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $2\pi$-periodic function $f$ is odd (this is clear from the Fourier series expansion); on $[0,\pi]$ its expression is given by

$$f(x)=\frac{\pi-x}{2}.$$

In summary (this follows from plotting $f$), due to symmetry and $2\pi$-periodicity $f$ is discontinuous at $x=0$, and continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]-\{0\}$. Then the Fourier sum

$$F_k(x):=\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{\sin nx}{n} $$

converges pointwise to $\tilde{f}$ on $[-\pi,\pi]-\{0\}$, where $\tilde{f}(x)=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ if $x\in(0,\pi]$ and $\tilde{f}(x)=\frac{x-\pi}{2}$ if $x\in[-\pi,0)$.

At $x=0$ we have

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} F_k(0)=\frac{f_+(0)+f_0(0)}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}, $$

with $f_+(0):=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)$ and $f_+(0):=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f(x)$.